# Little black "?" spaces?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, urlencode, decode

As seen in the included link to the picture.  I am getting these little black diamond shaped question marks, i'm guessing it has something to do with the url encoding.
http://prntscr.com/7gkxb

(the input field is a textarea for someone to enter a bio about themselves)

on the javascript side, i am using escape to encode it for the url.

```
var bio = document.getElementById('bioarea');
var bio_value = escape(bio.value);
```

then on the php side i am using urldecode to change it back

```
$bio = strip_tags($bio);
$bio = urldecode($bio);
```

i am using an ajax GET method to send the data for processing.  How can i have it so those "?"'s aren't there?

Comment: Can you show us some demos or test pages?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the URL encoding, it's the CHARACTER encoding. You've probably got some MS Word (Windows 1251) characters in a page defined as UTF-8.

See what type of character encoding you're using in your page header, make everything match.

Comment: Here are some [examples of header encodings](http://www.cybervaldez.com/how-to-remove-those-nasty-question-mark-with-a-diamond-symbols-from-appearing-in-your-website/2009/)(HTML and php), if you needed to know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you have some junk in your data, normally from copying and pasting.

Some times making sure your page is set to utf8 and your database if your using one.

More info here http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/

Comment: ahhh, thanks to both of you, i did copy and paste that data in there, when i don't copy and paste everything is ok. thanks

Comment: No probs don't forget to mark as solved and good luck with the rest off your project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have som other character than a "real space" at those positions, and your encoding is not the same on client- and server-side.

Maybe adding

```
$bio = utf8_encode($bio);
```

will fix this?